# Function property holding a reference to a document fragment: when to use cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, documentfragment

I'm having trouble understanding when a data assignment to an object is a reference and when a copy of the object is created.  I thought I understood but the following example doesn't fit my simple undestanding of it.

An event handler starts off a series of steps as follows.
`Promise.allSettled( [ gather_write, get_build ] ).then( test );`

Promises `gather_write` and `get_build` perform unrelated functions.  The first gathers some data from the DOM and writes it to the database.  The second retrieves data from the database and builds a document fragment.  If both fulfill, then a node in the DOM is replaced with the fragment.

It's too much code to show here, but `get_build`, after successfully getting the data from the database, invokes a separate function that builds the document fragment, and was returning its result as a property of the resolve object.  That worked fine; and then I wanted to try to provide options to the user in the event that `gather_write` rejected and `get_build` fulfilled, which requires the temporary storing of the document fragment. So, instead of returning it and passing it back to the `Promise.allSettled`, it is stored in a property of the function that builds it.

In the synchronous function `build` the code is set up as:

```
function build()
  {
    let f;
    try
      {
        f = document.createFragment();
        // ...build the fragment... 
        build.html = f;
      }
     catch(e)
      { }
     finally
      { f = null; }
   } // close build
```

Function `build` has to complete before the promise `get_build` can resolve, after which the `Promise.allSettled` can be evaluated; and, if both promises fulfill, the function to replace the DOM node with the newly built fragment stored in `build.html` can be invoked.  I thought that `build.html` would be a reference to the node object `f` and that, since `f` is set to null in the `finally` block, that would take place before all the above could complete, and when the code to use `build.html` was finally run it would be pointing to a null rather than the fragment. So, the assignment statement should be `build.html = f.cloneNode(true)`.

However, the process works fine with and without using `f.cloneNode`. Would you please explain why? I don't want the browser to take the steps to clone the fragment if it is unnecessary, but hesitate to exclude it without understanding why it is working without cloning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of every variable name as a pointer to a memory location. Setting a variable name to `null` does not alter anything in what the variable used to contain; all it does is change what the variable name points to, from the prior reference (here, to a document fragment) to the new reference (null). So, when you do

```
f = document.createFragment();
build.html = f;
```

then, no matter if/how the `f` variable name gets reassigned in the future, `build.html` will not be altered, because it continues to point to the document fragment. The only way the `build.html` would be altered would be if the fragment was *mutated* (such as assigning to a property of `f` before the reassignment, or calling one of the fragment's methods).

Here's another minimal example of this behavior:

```js
function foo() {
  let f = { prop: 'val' };
  foo.f = f;
  f = null;
}

foo();

console.log(foo.f);
```

Again, here, although `f` gets set to `null`, the object `{ prop: 'val' }` remains intact and unmutated, so `foo.f` gets a reference to that object, and continues to hold that reference even after `f` gets reassigned.

With your code, since the fragment in memory remains in memory, and the `build.html` retains a reference to that fragment even after `f` gets reassigned, cloning the fragment is just unnecessary overhead; feel free to leave it out.

Another way to visualize it is that your code:

```
function build() {
  let f;
  try {
    f = document.createFragment();
    // ...build the fragment... 
    build.html = f;
  } catch (e) {} finally {
    f = null;
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function build() {
  let f;
  try {
    // Create the object in memory:
    <MemRef#513513> = document.createFragment();
    // Point the variable `f` to that created object:
    f = <MemRef#513513>;
    // ...build the fragment... 
    build.html = <MemRef#513513>;
  } catch (e) {} finally {
    f = <MemRef#Null>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am so stupid. All my code is doing is making a reference to a reference, that is, I could have just set `build.html` to the documentFragment at the start and never declared `f`. I was concerned about causing a memory leak by not taking care of `f` but I need to make sure to break the connection to `build.html` after it is appended to the DOM or the failure code finishes. Thanks again.

Comment: "*All my code is doing is making a reference to a reference*". Nope, it's making *another* reference to the same object. :-)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out.  My experience in coding has been as a work tool I have to use to solve problems but I lack an undestanding of some of the basics that are needed to really know what you're doing.